# Get equal D and T slopes with tikz-timing

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-timing

I'm using the [`tikz-timing`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz-timing) package to create a bus timing diagram:

```
\begin{tikztimingtable}[timing/slope=0.5]
DT & 2D{}12D{}1D\\
CK & [H] 1H2{6T}2T\\
\end{tikztimingtable}
```

Now it occurs that the slope of `D{}D` is twice as long as the slope of `T`. That is in a way logical, because `T` is only one character (is that the reason?), but I now want a neat way to get the slopes even long.

Comment: The reason is not because `D{}D` are two characters and `T` is just one. As Qrrbrbirlbel's answer shows different slopes are used for different types of transitions. This was done by me (the package author) by design. The `D` transitions are double as long by default because the resulting cross would be too narrow IMHO otherwise. The `Z` transitions are only half, because the Y distance is only half either.

Comment: Yes, I made a mind-note about that after reading Qrrbrbirlbel's answer. Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the individual slopes. The [package manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/tikz-timing/tikz-timing.pdf) states in Table 4, page 7:

```
timing/slope=<0.0 – 1.0>    Sets slope for logic transitions.
                            This also sets dslope = 2 * slope,
                                           zslope = slope / 2.
timing/lslope=<0.0 – 1.0>   Sets slope for logic transitions only. Default: 0.1
timing/dslope=<0.0 – 1.0>   Sets slope for data transitions.       Default: 0.2
timing/zslope=<0.0 – 1.0>   Sets slope for Z transitions.          Default: 0.05
```

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-timing}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikztimingtable}[
    timing/lslope=.5,
    timing/dslope=.5,
]
    DT & 2D{}12D{}1D   \\
    CK & [H] 1H2{6T}2T \\
\end{tikztimingtable}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]